# How to create a service using Gson to consume a JSON request and give MySQL data as JSON response?

Tags: java, mysql, json

I have an input JSON which is like this:---

```
[
    {"request":{"prot_list":
       [
          {"protocolId":111111,"amendmentId":22222 },
          {"protocolId":2508007,"amendmentId":2508009}
       ]
    }
]
```

And my MySQL table "Protocol" contains:

```
+------------+-------------+---------------------+
| protocolId | amendmentId | prot_activated_date |
+------------+-------------+---------------------+
|     111111 |       22222 | 2017-05-29          |
|    2508007 |     2508009 | 2016-07-29          |
```

I need a json response as

```
["prot_list": [
        {
            "protocolId": 111111,
            "amendmentId": 22222,
            "prot_info": {
                "prot_activated_date": "07/29/2016"
            }
        },
        {
            "protocolId": 2508007,
            "amendmentId": 2508009,
            "prot_info": {
                "prot_activated_date": "07/29/2016"
            }
        }]
```

The main problem is I need this output JSON as response exactly when I am passing the input JSON to the service (I am using RESTeasy and Gson). 
By doing it seperatly in Java is easy. But I couldn't find a way for it to do it together. Kindly help me out.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Use Spring REST repository

Comment: I tried the same. But it works on single consume or response. Not consecutive request and the response together.

Comment: Since I am new in REST. I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone help me out by code. Please.